# CSS SubMenu Does Not Appear: Probably z-index issue

Tags: css

Trying to figure out how to display submenu when mouse over on parent page.
http://bit.ly/11DuQT5

If you check website with IE7 Compatibility mode then you will see submenus when you hover on some pages on main navigation menu. But those are not available on FF, IE10 and Google Chrome at all.

Could you please check z-index values and help me fix the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to your css

```
ul.webstun-hmenu li:hover ul {visibility: visible;}
```

Comment: Thanks @Abdul Malik now nav menu submenu is visible. However, there are new issues, at home page submenu appear behind slider, also third level pages should not be displayed when hovering submenu. But, they are displayed... Although I marked your response as answer I would appreciate your help on these as well.